# How to configure CDN GCP bucket access privileges

Tags: compliance, cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, cis-framework

We use GCP Cloud Storage and Cloud CDN to deliver some static assets (html/css/js/.jpg/.png). The buckets used to store those are public with anonymous access (i.e. allUsers in GCP terms).

On one hand Cloud CDN documentation seems to encourage this, but on the other hand we get findings of "Cloud storage buckets should not be anonymously or publicly accessible" from CIS and other compliance frameworks. For this kind of data, I don't see an issue and I'm pretty sure it's a pretty common thing do do.

Is everyone just ignoring those warnings or is there a better way I'm unaware of?

Comment: If the asset is public, why do you care if a user directly accesses the bucket instead of the CDN? Implementing authorization strategies that are not necessary is just another point of possible failure. Otherwise you can use a Signed URL to protect assets stored in Cloud Storage.

Comment: It seems fine to me, I ask because it gets flagged as a "severe threat".

Comment: Provide details in your question regarding "severe threat"

Comment: It's part of the CIS benchmark for GCP, "Ensure That Cloud Storage Bucket Is Not Anonymously or Publicly Accessible".

Comment: Most security rules have exceptions. If it is a requirement, then implement authorization. Just like a cooking recipe, a professional chef will use his own judgement based upon what he is preparing and serving.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading the description for this finding:

> "Allowing anonymous and/or public access grants permissions to anyone
> to access bucket content. Such access ***might not be desired if you
> are storing any sensitive data***. Hence, ensure that anonymous and/or
> public access to a bucket is not allowed." [emphasis mine]

In your case, it is desired... Nothing in digital security is binary.

The potential danger is that you use the same buckets for things that are not meant to be public. This is easy to do when you are looking for tools to use and you look to these nice, perfect buckets that are already in use.

So, don't forget about these buckets and the classification of data that is in them. Review the permissions and the data that's in them regularly.

But if they are meant to be public, let them be public.

But also don't merely ignore the warning. Let it be a reminder to check on those buckets to see if their use has unintentionally evolved past your current expectations.